# Center text in css with before tag

Tags: css

In a table I have this code:

```
...
  <td class="new"></td>
...
```

My Css is:

```
td.new:hover { background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.05); }
td.new:hover:before { content: "+"; text-align:center; }
```

How center my text in my td ?

Thanks.

Comment: do you want to center all text in td  or only the :before content ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to add text-align:center; to your .new class like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/Sg5BB/37/

```
td.new{text-align: center;}
td.new:hover { background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.05);}
td.new:hover:before { content: "+"; text-align:center; }
```